# PowerShell - executing a script on a remote machine giving error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

This following is not working for me -

```
%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Noninteractive -command "& Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Spider_LT_86" -ScriptBlock { msiexec.exe /i "D:\3PDInstallers\ETLBackgroundWorkerSetup.msi" /qn /l*vx "D:\3PDInstallers\logs" }"
```

all I need to do is run msiexec on a remote machine. I am assuming that the user running the script will have required access to the remote machine.

The script doesn't work even when the Computername points to the local computer (and running msiexec with the same logged in user works fine, so it doesn't look like a permissions issue) - I have ensured that the WinRM service is running, and I also disabled to firewall to check whether that is the cause of issue, but no luck so far. What am I missing here?

This is the full error but it pretty much lists all possibilities -

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using
Kerberos authentication: The network path was not found.
Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting He
lp topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

UPDATE:

When I use -Credentials with just the username, it pops up a login window to get my password and then on entering it, gives the following error - the user does have admin access so I don't know what's wrong.

The

[spider_lt_86] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: are you able to use enter-pssession computername then invoke your msiexec command ?

Comment: Ah, no.. that doesn't work either. Connecting itself (enter-pssession) seems to be the problem. Same error, even when I try to connect to the current computer.

Comment: try to do a enable-psremoting -force on the remote host

Comment: Thats already done.. it gives this - "WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine." followed by
"Set-WSManQuickConfig : WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network co
nnection type to either Domain or Private and try again"

However even if I turn off the firewall it doesn't work (so the exception shouldn't really cause the problem)

Comment: i had face some problems with winrm when wmi is broken or DNS malfunctions... Are you able to run wmi against the remote host? try something like `gwmi -Class win32_process -ComputerName remote_host`

Comment: yes that command worked fine without any problem

Comment: I'm affraid i've no more idea for the moment

Comment: except that you can try to run your command with psexec if you don't mind ...

Comment: What happens when you add -Credential "Username" to the command?

Comment: from powershell team : "Setting the correct network location type is very important for Windows PowerShell Remoting. You cannot enable Windows PowerShell Remoting on your machine if your connections are set to Public. It means you won’t be able to connect to this machine using Windows PowerShell Remoting." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/03/setting-network-location-to-private.aspx

Comment: @Kayasax thats not working either - I changed the connection to work instead of Public, even disabled the connection and tried locally - it still doesn't work

Comment: did you specify the credentials as per @StanleyDeBoer comment ?

Comment: Just did - have updated above.

Comment: your account may not be member of the remote amdinistrators group, you should really give a look here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847850.aspx

Comment: Ah success! I still need to figure how not to hard-code the username/pwd, but at least this is a start.. Thanks Kayasax and StanleyDeBoer, I owe you both a beer if you ever come to India!

Comment: you can use get-credential to ask for username and password at the script execution. Thnaks for the beer, India is a bit too far tough :). Please accept one answer so your question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a workaround than an answer but as you re able to use wmi why not try to create the remote process with it? Have a look here http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2011/06/powershell-launchstart-process-on.html?m=1

After comments exchange,  the problem is that you had not provide a credential with administrative privilege for the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the TrustedHosts on your computer to allow you to connect to other computers?

Run this on the computer you are trying to remote from.

```
Set-Item  wsman::localhost\client\TrustedHosts *  
Restart-Service WinRm
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing is clear, the error message "The network path was not found" gives no indication of what the underlying issue is.  I saw a post in a [Microsoft forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/78981c45-de6c-486d-b31e-1497f55dc9c4/winrm-the-network-path-was-not-found-help?forum=winserverpowershell) where a respondent stated it used to work and now did not.  That is where I found myself.  I verified that I could ping and that I could net view shares, so I knew that the network portions were functional.  I rebooted the source server and that did not seem to help.  Once I **rebooted the target server**, the WinRM error went away and everything started to work again.  It is not clear whether a service was down or misbehaving or if there was something less obvious going on.  After the reboot I got one more failure (out of about 20 attempts), but random failures are not so uncommon in our environment.

I will leave this behind just in case it helps someone else.